# The style of QPushButton didn't take effect

Tags: qt

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

The code in qss file:

```
.QPushButton:disabled{background-color: red;}
.QPushButton#m_pUploadBtn:disabled{background-color: yellow;}
```

But the style of "m_pUploadBtn" didn't take effect.

```
.QPushButton:hover{color: red;}
.QPushButton#m_pUploadBtn:hover{color: yellow;}
```

Only the disabled attribute didn't take effect. 
hover, pressed take effect.

Answer (score -1):

This is my minimum example for your conditions. It works properly. Show your example that didn't take effect for disabled buttons.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

namespace {
    static const auto STYLE_SHEET =
        ".QPushButton:disabled{background-color: red;}"
        ".QPushButton#m_pUploadBtn:disabled{background-color: yellow;}"
        ".QPushButton:hover{color: red;}"
        ".QPushButton#m_pUploadBtn:hover{color: yellow;}";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget wid;

    auto btn1 = new QPushButton( "Btn", &wid );
    auto btn2 = new QPushButton( "UploadBtn", &wid );
    btn2->setObjectName( QStringLiteral( "m_pUploadBtn" ) );
    auto btn3 = new QPushButton( "DisabledBtn", &wid );
    btn3->setDisabled( true );
    auto btn4 = new QPushButton( "DisabledUploadBtn", &wid );
    btn4->setObjectName( QStringLiteral( "m_pUploadBtn" ) );
    btn4->setDisabled( true );

    auto lay = new QVBoxLayout( &wid );
    lay->addWidget( btn1 );
    lay->addWidget( btn2 );
    lay->addWidget( btn3 );
    lay->addWidget( btn4 );

    wid.setStyleSheet( STYLE_SHEET );
    wid.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```